# How to make a VMware Player VM discoverable in local network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, netdiscover

I have a Debian VM running in VMware Player and I can't find that VM via `netdiscover`. I'm able to ping the machine, but discovering it or finding it in my router doesn't work, I tried Bridged, NAT and Host-only. The Debian VM gets a local IP in the 192.168 subnet. When I'm scanning the network with `netdiscover` I can find all other devices connected to my network but finding the VM seems impossible. I think I have to configure the network adapter with `vmware-netcfg` but I'm not sure how to. There are many YouTube videos about people doing this just on the fly without changing the config but on my `5.6.0-kali2-amd64` it doesn't work like that.

Comment: what port does netdiscover uses to probe machines on your network,is that port open on virtual machine.

Comment: It uses ARP, so I guess it's TCP. It should be open as I can ping the machine.